# iPhone - a UI component that looks like an Alert box - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to know what this [UI component](http://getandroidstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/SMS-Popup-Andorid.png) is called ? It looks like an `Alert` but has `textfeilds` and `buttons` in it ?

1.) What is this UIComponent called ?
2.) Is there any video tutorial which shows how to implement this ? (If so link) or any tutorials that discuss the implementation of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's UIAlertView
2. Here is the tutorial to make custom [UIAlertView](http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/08/14/custom-uialertview-color-chooser/)

Answer (score 1):

That is an Android component, there is no equivalent in iOS.

There is the UIAlertView, but you cannot edit text within it.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertView

If you want to be able to let users edit text in the component, you have to create it from scratch, e.g. create a UIView and add a UITextView to it and some UIButtons and create the functionality to display/dismiss the component yourself.

Answer (score 0):

AlertView

```
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                        message:@"Message" 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

The component on iPhone is called a UIAlertView. You can add subviews in it to get text-fields, although this is not recommended by Apple - but you won't get rejected either. In iOS5, there are dedicated UIAlertView types for this. If you are building for iOS5, this is the method you should use.